# Appsync - Masking a field in mutation response which is required by subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I'm building a chat based application using Appsync with the following mutation and subscription.

However, the chat room is moderated and depending on the chat settings (which is controlled by a moderator), the messages can be either visible to everyone or visible to the moderator alone.

For security reasons, I don't want to send the "receiverId" in the response of the createMessage mutation.

But, I'm not able to create a subscription with filter on "receiverId" if this field is not present in the response of the mutation.

Is there any alternative way to achieve this chat behaviour ?

```
mutation createMessage {
  createMessage(input: {
    chatId: "chatId1",
    userId: "userA",
    content: "sample message"
  }) {
    id, 
    content,
    chatId,
    userId,
    receiverId
  }
}

and a corresponding subscription

subscription onCreateMessage {
  onCreateMessage(input: {receiverId: "userB"
  }) {
    id, 
    content,
    chatId,
    userId,
    receiverUserId
  }
}
```